# Can't create room with Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been using the multiplayer feature of the Google Play Game Services for my game and recently I cannot create a room anymore.

It's been a long time since I haven't touched this part of code so I don't understand what makes it failing. I am testing on a Nexus 4 and a Motorola Razr, both connected to the internet by Wifi.

First I sign in using Google+ and onSignInSucceeded() is called. Then I call this piece of code :

```
public void startQuickMatch() {
    // quick-start a game with 1 to 3 randomly selected opponents
    final int MIN_OPPONENTS = 1, MAX_OPPONENTS = 3;
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(MIN_OPPONENTS, MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
    //Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(2, 2, 0);
    RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    //keepScreenOn();
    getGamesClient().createRoom(rtmConfigBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "createRoom called");
}
```

But instead of creating the room and putting me in the waiting room, I get those logs that don't help me, since they are not clear for me and they can't be find on google.

```
06-24 13:10:34.366: D/SuperNinjaRun(29402): createRoom called
06-24 13:10:34.376: E/DataConnectionManager(21359): tearDown() called when network is NOT ready for match !
06-24 13:10:34.426: I/libjingle(21359): Token type:OAuth2
06-24 13:10:34.426: I/libjingle(21359): Final XMPP server hostname talk.google.com port to 5222
06-24 13:10:34.436: D/games_rtmp:Libjingle(21359): Release: call nativeRelease
06-24 13:10:34.436: W/RealTimeAndroidService(21359): Could not prepare network for the room.
06-24 13:10:34.496: W/InputMethodManagerService(551): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@42843b40 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42b617d0
06-24 13:10:34.776: I/libjingle(21359): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
06-24 13:10:34.976: I/libjingle(21359): BeginSSL: gmail.com
06-24 13:10:35.797: I/libjingle(21359): Starting Jingle info task.
06-24 13:10:35.797: I/libjingle(21359): IbbDataTask::ProcessStart() called:
06-24 13:10:35.807: I/libjingle(21359): ProcessStart()::Sending Jingle info stanza.
06-24 13:10:35.907: I/libjingle(21359): OnJingleInfo called. Setting relay/stun hosts.
06-24 13:10:36.928: E/libjingle(21359): Error(libjingleclient.cpp:232): Exiting with unfinished tasks.
06-24 13:10:36.928: I/libjingle(21359): Cleanup
```

And sometimes it also gives me those logs several seconds later :

```
06-24 13:30:48.043: E/Volley(1165): [80] il.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1whitelisted/applications?language=en_US&platformType=ANDROID
06-24 13:30:48.043: E/GameAgent(1165): Unable to retrieve applications from network
06-24 13:30:48.043: I/GameAgent(1165): {"code":400,"errors":[{"message":"Invalid applicationId with value ReplaceMe.","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}
06-24 13:30:48.103: D/SyncManager(531): failed sync operation raphael.royer.rivard@gmail.com u0 (com.google), com.google.android.gms.games, USER, earliestRunTime 28048, SyncResult: stats [ numIoExceptions: 1]
```

Anyone has an idea of where the problem could come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working now, I forgot a `break;` in a switch... so the player was signing out right before trying to create the room...

Comment: I cant create a room. Can you please provide me a sample code?

Comment: My post is 6 years old, it's been a long time since I haven't developped android games... Good luck!